# Convert varbinary to varchar with encoding in presto sql and AWS athena

Tags: unicode, presto, amazon-athena, trino

I'm using AWS Athena.

I have a string field which holds base64 encoding of a DOMString by javascript's btoa (so, not utf-8 string but instead, 16-bit-encoded string).

So, the string `Fútbol España` is stored as `Rvp0Ym9sIEVzcGHxYQ==` (and not `RsO6dGJvbCBFc3Bhw7Fh` which is the base64 of the utf-8 encoding)

How can I decode this string in AWS athena (presto) SQL?
if I use

`select from_utf8(from_base64('Rvp0Ym9sIEVzcGHxYQ=='))`

I get `F�tbol Espa�a`... is there a from_ascii or something similar, which accepts varbinary and encoding and performs the decode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to do this in Presto today, but I filed an issue to add it: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/1035

Comment: Note that Athena is training Presto by many, many releases, and was also recently forked, so it may take a long time before this ends up in Athena.